# Django: How to properly render SplitDateTimeWidget for DateTimeRangeField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-widget

Online material (docs, code) for django's (postgres-specific) [range fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/forms/ranges/) is lacking. I tried overriding the widget for [DateTimeRangeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/forms/ranges/#DateTimeRangeField), but can't get it to show 2 pretty date-time inputs using [SplitDateTimeWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#SplitDateTimeWidget) (start datetime, end datetime) for my field. I have settled for overriding the `type` attribute and getting the following okayish output, without this, it's just plain `type="text"`.

**Current behaviour:**

[image: Current okayish behaviour]

**Expected behaviour:** Following, but 2 of them.

[image]

**My models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import DateTimeRangeField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    datetimerange = DateTimeRangeField()
    ...
```

**My admin.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.postgres.forms.ranges import RangeWidget, DateTimeRangeField


class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            "datetimerange": RangeWidget(
                forms.SplitDateTimeWidget(
                    date_attrs={"type": "date"}, time_attrs={"type": "time"},
                ),
            )
        }


@admin.register(models.MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm
```

I tried playing around with (inheriting from) the default field `DateTimeRangeField` but no luck there as well.

Comment: Having the same issue, did you find a solution? I just get empty <input> tags...

Comment: @ÖzerS. I ended up splitting the field into 2 datetimes for this and other reasons. But in any case the above would still work, albeit, without the nice-looking separate date & time fields for both from & to datetime.

Comment: Haha, I did exactly the same, good old start_date and end_date, it's so much easier. I really tried a lot, but the support for the DateTimeRangeField is just not there. I think you can achieve it with custom widgets etc., but in the end you will have more code than simple start/end.